# VISUAL STUDIO 2015 and Angular 2

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I followed the steps mentioned in [VISUAL STUDIO 2015 QUICKSTART](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html) and was able setup and execute the application successfully in windows 10.

My package.json has scripts section similar to the one mentioned below

```
scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    ....
```

But when I execute below npm command

```
 npm run build
```

it displays below error

> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\KISHORE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
>   npm ERR! node v6.9.1
>   npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 2
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script 'tsc -p src/'.

Any idea what could be the reason for this error.